# Unable to store image to internal storage

Tags: android

Hi I know this question has been asked before but I am unable to get this code to work. I want to save the image I captured from the camera to internal storage so that it is inaccessible to the user. My code is below:

```
 private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I am using the below code to get the uri of my image by passing in the previously obtained path to this method.

```
private Uri loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{


        File f=new File(path, "profile.jpg");
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(f.toString());


    return uri;
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any error ????? Have you give permission ?

Comment: no error.I dont think you need permissions for storing to internal storage but I have given anyway.

Comment: I actually want to make sure that the user is unable to access these images

Comment: `I know this has been asked before but I have tried everything but I am unable to perform this operation. `. It is unclear where you are talking about.

Comment: `using the loadImageFromStorage method to get the uri of the file and then using it to access my image. `. For what do you need an uri? And there is no code that accesses a file. So what is the problem? Pretty unclear.

Comment: `// path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`. No. That will not give you that path. Please try again.

Comment: I am using loadImageFromStorage to get back a uri for my image. I need either the uri or the filepath to send this image to the server.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,I'm also getting error when used like you

```
 private String savePicture(Activity context, Bitmap bitmapImage) throws IOException {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name) + "/");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        boolean b = mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
    }
    File imageToUpload = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    if (!imageToUpload.exists())
        imageToUpload.createNewFile();

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageToUpload);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        bitmapImage.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageToUpload.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: This is saving to external storage?

Comment: I want it stored in the internal storage so that the user is unable to access these images.

Comment: yes I faced same issue, file created but content size is 0 when try to store in internal storage that's why I choose this

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
It will store file in internal storage with no permission needed

Also please comment if answer helpful

```
 private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(getFilesDir(),"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: I hope you seen difference in below line

File mypath=new File(getFilesDir(),"profile.jpg");

Even I have also tested it working at my end

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. I am able to save the image to external storage but I dont why the internal storage code is not working.